# cocos2d - process data in the background

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i am developing a iphone application with cocos2d and i need a function for updating content. How can i start a new work thread that will send some request in the background and will not pause the main application/gui thread? I have searched through the web and can not find a decent example. Thanks!

Comment: The same way you create any other background thread. Cocos2d is just a lot of classes to help you do fast graphics - it's not a replacement for iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use NSOperation and NSOperationQueue for this.

Comment: what about GCD? Is it better to use GCD or NSOperationQueue? The downside of GCD it runs on iOS 4 and greater.

Comment: Depends if you are targeting at iOS4+ or not! NSOperationQueue (since iOS4) uses GCD internally anyway - just a different abstraction

Comment: as I didn't use GCD, I cannot compare them, and, as Nick said, it depends on target platform.